# winform not get the focus

Tags: c#, winforms, focus

all,

I just want to make a winform that can cover all the screen and it cannot get the focus. But it still keeps on the top of the screen. It means that users can also do their other operations with this topmost winform.

Any thoughs. Thanks all of you!

Comment: Did you try anything so far? Please read [FAQ] and [ask]

Comment: I tried topmost and createparams. They aren't what I want and I am still figuring out a way to solve this problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
public class Form1 : Form {
  [DllImport("user32")]
  private static extern bool SetLayeredWindowAttributes(IntPtr hwnd, int crKey, byte alpha, int flags);
  public Form1(){
     InitializeComponent();
     Load += (s,e) => {
       TopMost = true;
       FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
       WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
       ShowInTaskbar = false;
       SetOpacity(50);//try this to see it in action :)
     };
  }
  protected override CreateParams CreateParams {
      get {
           CreateParams cp = base.CreateParams;
           cp.ExStyle |= 0x20 | 0x80000;   // WS_EX_TRANSPARENT and WS_EX_LAYERED
           return cp;
      }
  }
  //This is called to set your form opacity, by default (after applying above ex-styles) the opacity is 0.
  public void SetOpacity(byte opacity){
      SetLayeredWindowAttributes(Handle, 0, opacity, 0x2);//LWA_ALPHA = 0x2
  }
  public void DecorateForm(){
     //Your code to decorate form...
  }
}
```

The code above is to create some kind of `Click through` form, that form is not interactive but can display everything on top of other windows without preventing user from interacting with them. I'm using this technique to show a `faded image of my love` on my computer screen, especially when looking with a low viewing angle, I can see the image more clearly. That's so sweet.

Comment: @KeqinDou you're welcome. If it helps, please click (1 time) on the tick sign below vote number to accept my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Set the TopMost property of your form to true. That will keep the form on top even if other forms or windows have focus. If new TopMost-forms is created they will cover the last one.

myForm.TopMost = True;

If you don't want the window to let clicks through you probably rather need to tap into GDI+ or DX.

But you could also experiment with the [SetWindowLongPtr](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644898%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function to set the attributes of your window. [Here's a link](http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/csharp/threads/288007/create-transparent-overlay-on-desktop) to someone that seems to have done what you're after.

Comment: Thank you for your response. But this way if I click on the form it will get the focus. I don't want it to get the focus when I click on it.

Answer (score 0):

as tophe said

```
public Form1()
  {
     InitializeComponent();
     TopMost = true;
  }
```

will keep the form on top.
for the focus you can

```
private Form masterForm;
  public Form2(Form master)
  {
     masterForm = master;
     InitializeComponent();
     GotFocus += new EventHandler(Form2_GotFocus);
  }

  void Form2_GotFocus(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
     masterForm.Focus();
  }
```

and that way if the secondary form get focus it give it away to the master form

Comment: Thanks for your help. But I just want to make a blur cover on all the screen and users can still do their operations. This way I think can just give the focus to the pointed form or process but not what I want.

Comment: please give me more information. what do you mean when you say " blur cover on all the screen and users can still do their operations"

Comment: It means that I just want to add a cover on all the screen which the user will see the original windows content with some blur effect and they still can finish their operations on the original windows. In another way, the original content(windows desktop or others) will be a layer and the cover which I add is another layer. The users can move their mouse between these two layers and when they click or other operations done are on the content layer not on the cover which I add. Thanks! Is this clear enough?